# I want to create slide down panel

Tags: jquery

I want to create slide down panel but its not working can you please suggest me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
$(Document).Ready(function(){
    $("#flip").Click(funcTion(){
        $("#panel").slidedown("slow");
    });
});
</script>


</head>
<body>

<div id="flip">Click to slide down panel</div>
<div id="panel"> This is content</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Google` first then ask.

Comment: @janardan : few changes has to be done check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you have include library and you can't write function is like funcTion or slideDown can slidedown

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#flip").click(function() {
                    $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
                });
            });
        </script>

        <style> 
            #panel, #flip {
                padding: 5px;
                text-align: center;
                background-color: #e5eecc;
                border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
            }

            #panel {
                padding: 50px;
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="flip">Click to slide down panel</div>
        <div id="panel">This is content</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check script tag** You forgot your **script** tag and the library too
**and hide the div first which you want to slide**

[**Your Working DEMO here click**](https://jsfiddle.net/d8doyc9r/8/)

```
<html>
        <head>
<!--import your jquery library-->
        <script>
        $(Document).Ready(function(){
            $("#flip").Click(funcTion(){
                $("#panel").slidedown("slow");
            });

    });
    </script>
```